# Baked normals applied incorrectly on final rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

I had multiple texture images on one material. I baked them to 3 different maps: diffuse, normal and specular. Now I'm trying to make final rendering node system (Cycles engine). Here's what I have there.
[image]

When I plug my normal map into shader through *Bump* node I've got the whole kind of rough and shaggy. Could you please explain how to apply normal and further specular maps here?

Here is how the mesh looks like when normal map plugged in. I have bump information only on his clothes but not the face.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A normal map isn't a bump map.  Use a normal map node instead of your bump node.  Specular map depends on exactly what the bake was, and what it was from (specular color?) but it can't go into the material you have shown, because that material has no specular component, only diffuse.

Comment: I tried to add Normal map node instead and the normal information doesn't display at all

Comment: As for the specular map, it was baked from Specular color exactly. For this one I'm gonna change shader to Principled. But anyway issue with normals is still unclear.